# How to create regions on App Fabric via Powershell

Tags: .net, caching, powershell, appfabric

I think the title is clear, I'm surfing the web about an hour but every single page talks about creating regions dynamically using .net. I'm sure we have a command to execute on powershell. do you know it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Link to an example in .NET? PowerShell is based on .NET and can import .NET namespaces so such translating from a C# sample is usually trivial.

Comment: what is a region with respect to appfabric? never heard of it. appfabric caching or wcf hosting?

Comment: @x0n There's a description of regions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790985.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no Powershell commandlet out of the box for creating/managing regions.

The solution - write one!

As Daniel Richnak says in the comments, Powershell is .NET under the covers, and this means you can write extra Powershell commandlets to fill in the gaps.

A commandlet is a regular class that inherits from `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet`, and it's decorated with the `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet` attribute as well. Making it work is then a matter of overriding the `ProcessRecord` method. Command-line parameters are implemented as properties on the class, decorated with the `System.Management.Automation.Parameter` attribute. So a commandlet for creating regions would look something like:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "CacheRegion")]
public class NewCacheRegion : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1)]
    public string Cache { get; set; }
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 2)]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();

        DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory();
        DataCache cache = factory.GetCache(Cache);

        try
        {
            cache.CreateRegion(Region);
        }
        catch (DataCacheException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == DataCacheErrorCode.RegionAlreadyExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("There is already a region named {0} in the cache {1}.", Region, Cache));
            }
        }
    }
}
```